# Changing static attributes of nested class

Tags: python

I have following code which allows me to set attributes of instance by passing them in `**kwargs`

```py
class A: 
    name = 'dog'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        for k in kwargs: 
            setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
    class B: 
        x = 4
```

For example, I can do `a = A(**{ "name" : "cat", "hobby" : "eat" })` to get an Instance `a` of `A` which gives

```
>>> a.name
'cat'
>>> a.hobby
'eat'
```

However, `a = A(**{ "name" : "cat", "hobby" : "eat", "B.x" : 0 })` fails to set `a.B.x = 0`

```
>>> a.B.x
4
```

So, what do I pass inplace of `"B.x" : 0` to get `a.B.x = 0`

Edit: I'm doing this to maintain config options as properties.

Example, I've following code

```
class GameConfig:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        for k in kwargs: 
            setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
    class Pacman:
        speed = 35
    class Blinky
        speed = 40
    class Inky:
        speed = 40
```

I'd like to create an Instance of above config so that I can get pacman speed as, `config.Pacman.speed` etc.

Comment: `setattr(self, 'B.x', ...)` is not the same as `self.B.x = ...`. `setattr` doesn't evaluate the attribute name as code, i.e. a `.` in there doesn't resolve as a nested attribute. I would question why you need a "nested class" in the first place. It's not terribly pythonic.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @deceze I'm maintain config properties in outermost object A. And, I'm thinking about namespacing properties into nested classes. I'll edit to show an example.

Comment: Your initializer code is an antipattern - it defeats the whole point of using classes instead of plain dicts. And nested classes don't work as you seem to expect - they become class attributes of their "containing" class, so two instances of `A` will share the same `B`. I don't really know what you're trying to achieve with this, but chances are it's not the solution.

Comment: **Don't use nested classes**. They don't do what they want, or what you think they're doing. They don't work for your purposes. In your case, you probably want a base class `Character`, then subclass that into `Pacman` and `Ghost`, then subclass `Ghost` into `Inky, Blinky...`. But don't try to define those subclasses inside `GameConfig`.

Comment: Note that the point of ``**kwargs``  is to pass in *keywords*, e.g. ``A(name="cat", hobby="eat")``. Creating a dictionary and unpacking it to keywords, only to have it re-packed as a dictionary is a waste. Just pass the dictionary directly -- and while you are at it, just *use* the dictionary directly, without a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a "dot-aware" `setattr`, which can make nested assignments (not just for static class attributes). This works by splitting the attribute name at any `.`, using all but the last part for lookup.

```
def set_dotattr(obj, names, value):
    """
    Sets the named, dotted attribute on the given object to the specified value.

    setattr(x, 'y.z', v) is equivalent to ``x.y.z = v''
    """
    # split the dotted name into a path to follow and final attribute name
    *path, name = names.split('.')
    # follow the path to find obj on which to set attribute
    for part in path:
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    setattr(obj, name, value)
```

---

You can use this modified `set_dotattr` in your class to directly digest names such as `B.x`. Note that for your pattern to be useful, you must define or instantiate the nested classes *per instance*.

```
# B exists separate from A
class B:
    x = 4

class A: 
    name = 'dog'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # allow for separate B state per A instance
        self.B = B()
        # apply possibly nested attributes
        for k in kwargs: 
            set_dotattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
```

This allows creating `A` instances and setting attributes of the respective `B`.

```
>>> A(**{'B.x': 42}).B.x
42
```